# Como obtener en PHP desde un JSON el valor de un atributo, si tiene nombre de elementos repetidos?

Tags: php, array, json

Hola tengo este json y me gustaria imprimir en un php ciertos valores como por ejemplo  el codec_name del index "1" que en este caso arroja h264, y valores como el width & height que yo creo que ya accediendo a uno, podria saber como acceder a los demás.

```
    {
       "streams": [
         {
           "index": 0,
           "codec_name": "timed_id3",
           "disposition": {
             "dub": 0,
             "timed_thumbnails": 0
        },
           "tags": {
             "variant_bitrate": "3578498"
        }
    },
    {
           "index": 1,
           "codec_name": "h264",
           "width": 1920,
           "height": 1080,
           "disposition": {
             "dub": 0,
             "timed_thumbnails": 0
        },
           "tags": {
             "variant_bitrate": "3578498"
        }
    },
    {
           "index": 2,
           "codec_name": "aac",
           "disposition": {
             "default": 0,
             "timed_thumbnails": 0
        },
           "tags": {
            "variant_bitrate": "3578498"
        }
    }
],
"format": {
    "filename": "https://5gt584fghj9c9.streamlock.net/produce8/videoproduce8/playlist.m3u8",
    "nb_streams": 3,
    "probe_score": 100
  }
 }
```

Este es mi codigo de php con el que intente acceder:

```
     <?php

      $url = 'http://apiurl.com/test.json';
      $data = file_get_contents($url);
      $data = json_decode($data);

      $video = $data->streams->codec_name;
      echo $video;
      ?>
```

Hay hasta 3 codec_name en 3 bloques diferentes, quisiera acceder a cada uno de ellos, por separado.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es bastante sencillo:

yo armaría variables en la medida que voy detectando que existen:

Documentacion:
[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), [variable de nombre de variable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php).

```
<?php
$jsontext = '{"streams":[{"index":0,"codec_name":"timed_id3","disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":1,"codec_name":"h264","width":1920,"height":1080,"disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":2,"codec_name":"aac","disposition":{"default":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}}],"format":{"filename":"https://5gt584fghj9c9.streamlock.net/produce8/videoproduce8/playlist.m3u8","nb_streams":3,"probe_score":100}}';

$data = json_decode($jsontext);

var_dump($data);

$c=0;
$loop = true;

while($loop){
    if(isset($data->streams[$c])){
        ${'cname_'.$c} = $data->streams[$c]->codec_name;
    }else{
        $loop=false; // se detiene el loop inmediatamente no existan datos
    }
    $c++;
}

//antes de usar el dato valida que se recibio:

if(isset($cname_0)){
    var_dump($cname_0);
}

if(isset($cname_1)){
    var_dump($cname_1);
}

if(isset($cname_2)){
    var_dump($cname_2);
}
```

Otra Forma de hacer con una estructura de control `for` puede ser esta:

[documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php)

```
<?php
$jsontext = '{"streams":[{"index":0,"codec_name":"timed_id3","disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":1,"codec_name":"h264","width":1920,"height":1080,"disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":2,"codec_name":"aac","disposition":{"default":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}}],"format":{"filename":"https://5gt584fghj9c9.streamlock.net/produce8/videoproduce8/playlist.m3u8","nb_streams":3,"probe_score":100}}';

$data = json_decode($jsontext);

var_dump($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data->streams); $i++) {
    ${'cname_'.$i} = $data->streams[$i]->codec_name;
}

if(isset($cname_0)){
    var_dump($cname_0);
}

if(isset($cname_1)){
    var_dump($cname_1);
}

if(isset($cname_2)){
    var_dump($cname_2);
}
```

Otra Forma de hacer con una estructura de control `foreach` puede ser esta:

[documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
<?php
$jsontext = '{"streams":[{"index":0,"codec_name":"timed_id3","disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":1,"codec_name":"h264","width":1920,"height":1080,"disposition":{"dub":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}},{"index":2,"codec_name":"aac","disposition":{"default":0,"timed_thumbnails":0},"tags":{"variant_bitrate":"3578498"}}],"format":{"filename":"https://5gt584fghj9c9.streamlock.net/produce8/videoproduce8/playlist.m3u8","nb_streams":3,"probe_score":100}}';

$data = json_decode($jsontext);

var_dump($data);

foreach ($data->streams as $clave => $valor) {
    ${'cname_'.$clave} = $valor->codec_name;
}

if(isset($cname_0)){
    var_dump($cname_0);
}

if(isset($cname_1)){
    var_dump($cname_1);
}

if(isset($cname_2)){
    var_dump($cname_2);
}
```

Existe tambien otros métodos para la navegabilidad de objetos y arrays,  como: `array_filter`, `array_walk_recursive`, `array_walk` que puedes ir estudiando para que tenga una idea de todo lo que puedes hacer ...

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, de hecho ahorita por ejemplo ya navegue hasta el codec 1, y ya me devuelve: string(4) "h264" , me das un tip para darle format, y ya solo imprimir el valor entre comillas h264?

Comment: si era con echo, gracias!!

Comment: Buena respuesta, responde la pregunta, pero hay mejores formas de recorrer arreglos, con un `for()` simple evitas el uso de contador y bandera; con `foreach()` es todavía más simple. De cualquier forma... +1

Comment: @Triby es que el escenario dado por el usuario es bastante especifico no vi la necesidad de profundizar en la navegabilidad de un objeto ... de lo contrario... seria un duplicado de esta otra respuesta que di hace unas semanas XD

Comment: En todo caso, podrías haber orientado la respuesta a hacerlo con un ciclo y, adicionalmente, acceder directo a la propiedad deseada: `$data->streams[1]->codec_name`

Comment: hay le agregue un ejemplo con un for

Comment: @Triby  Gracias a ambos por ayudarme, de hecho ya me habían ayudado hace unos días, gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 1):

Bebes  recorrer el array de objetos

```html
if(is_object($data->streams) || is_array($data->streams))
  foreach($data->streams as $k => $value){
    var_dump($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Me sale un error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/dir/public_html/user/fes.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/dirpublic_html/user/fes.php on line 9

Comment: he modificado la respuesta. prueba y me comentas

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo!!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que una de las maneras más sencillas en las que puedes afrontar tu problema, es hacer uso de las múltiples [funciones para manejo de los arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), especialmente [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) y [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), de la siguiente manera:

```
// Array donde almacenarás los nuevos datos
$array = [];

// String json con el formato de tu data
$json = "{\"streams\":[{\"index\":0,\"codec_name\":\"timed_id3\",\"disposition\":{\"dub\":0,\"timed_thumbnails\":0},\"tags\":{\"variant_bitrate\":\"3578498\"}},{\"index\":1,\"codec_name\":\"h264\",\"width\":1920,\"height\":1080,\"disposition\":{\"dub\":0,\"timed_thumbnails\":0},\"tags\":{\"variant_bitrate\":\"3578498\"}},{\"index\":2,\"codec_name\":\"aac\",\"disposition\":{\"default\":0,\"timed_thumbnails\":0},\"tags\":{\"variant_bitrate\":\"3578498\"}}],\"format\":{\"filename\":\"https://5gt584fghj9c9.streamlock.net/produce8/videoproduce8/playlist.m3u8\",\"nb_streams\":3,\"probe_score\":100}}";

// Convertimos ese JSON en un array, pasando como bandera el argumento true
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Obtenemos el único valor que cumpla con tu criterio, es decir index = 1
$value = array_filter($data['streams'], function($d){
   if($d['index'] === 1) { 
      return $d; 
   } 
});

// Recorremos ese array obtenido, que será multidimensional
// Para obtener un nuevo array que le pasamos por referencia al array_walk
array_walk_recursive($value, function($val, $key) use (&$array) {
   $array[$key] = $val; 
} );

// Respuesta que se debe obtener:
array(7) {
    ["index"]=> int(1)
    ["codec_name"]=> string(4) "h264"
    ["width"]=> int(1920)
    ["height"]=> int(1080)
    ["dub"]=> int(0)
    ["timed_thumbnails"]=> int(0)
    ["variant_bitrate"]=> string(7) "3578498"
}

var_dump($array);
```

Ya sabiendo que tu data requerida está en un nuevo array, solo debes hacer algo como:

`$array['width']`;

O sea lo que necesites. [Te dejo un link para que veas cómo funciona](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/079bb1b30eab1774c89344c404a35cc359be22bd)

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: No es nada. Recuerda que dentro del filter solo basta con que hagas el **1** dinámico según lo que necesites y puedes obtener cualquier atributo del json que obtienes.

Comment: Si, ya entendí tu código, muy bueno la verdad, gracias nuevamente hermano!